# Selenium Python - Get Table Data Instead of JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I need some help on a data **Scraping** Task on this : https://soilhealth.dac.gov.in/NewHomePage/NutriPage
I Managed to fill the dropdown Menu and to click on view using this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://soilhealth.dac.gov.in/NewHomePage/NutriPage"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('NutriCatId'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Sample Wise')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('CycleId'))
select.select_by_visible_text('All Cycle')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('State_Code'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Andaman And Nicobar Islands')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('District_Code'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Nicobars')
driver.find_element_by_id('s').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

I need to **scrape** the table data from the source code, instead of having it on soup_level1 xml, I only have the javascript code.
Any help to know if **scraping** the data is possible using Selenium is possible and how can I do it would be awsome.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey the below code does the job. But it is slow since the table is huge and it takes a bit of time to parse. I observed that the report has an export option available so do try to download it directly using Selenium. Oh and for the explanation the report is generated as an iframe which is different from the default source of the page so you need to switch to that frame to get the info. Do let me know for any clarification. The required data is in df variable.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Mar 24 11:08:32 2020

@author: prakh
"""

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

url = "https://soilhealth.dac.gov.in/NewHomePage/NutriPage"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/prakh/Documents/PythonScripts/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get(url)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('NutriCatId'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Sample Wise')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('CycleId'))
select.select_by_visible_text('All Cycle')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('State_Code'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Andaman And Nicobar Islands')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('District_Code'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Nicobars')
driver.find_element_by_id('s').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
#soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

#src = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report"]/iframe').get_attribute("src")

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report"]/iframe'))
time.sleep(10)

html = driver.page_source
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-3]

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Done the job for me. Doesn't matter if it slow, it will be a run once code. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left handside in my answer. And feel free to up vote the answer.

Comment: Upvoted, since my reputation is less than 15 it's not taken in account :(. Thanks again.